# opening sql file hangs most of the editors but not notepad++

Tags: macos, text-editors, sql

I sometimes need to modify url in big sql files. I usually open it up in some editor and do search and replace. On windows machine notepad++ works perfectly, it never hangs and feels snappy to show blocks of text. Now on my mac I cannot get anything to work properly! I have smultron 4 and it is sluggish. Any good software you recommend?

I imagine command line would be easiest with grep. But really do I have to mess with complicated syntax of grep or find to do this?

Comment: Why are you making changes to the file and not directly to the database?

Comment: @Dean because you need to keep version control or it is test data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something similar in style and power to Notepad++, try using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

This is cross-platform (based on Python) and has loads of community supplied add-ins to make it a very powerful IDE and development platform.

The only disadvantage is that it isn't totally free - it pops up a reminder to purchase every few dozen saves.

This is now my chosen IDE and text editor.

It is perfectly happy with very large files and even has a graphical map of the file if you want to use it for navigation.

Comment: While it won't hang, sublime text 2 still takes a while to load the entire file before it will allow you to view/edit it (Notepad++ displays the file instantly while it's loading it). Still the best editor out there though, worth every penny for me.

Comment: I've seen sublime text 2 before. But 50$ price turned made me walk away. I didn't know they had free version, I'm trying it out... it looks amazing.

Comment: I agree that the price is rather high but he doesn't make a big thing of the free use and it is per user so you can use it on as many machines as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Choose your poison

[Aquamacs puts the Mac in Emacs](http://aquamacs.org/)
[Vim (Vi IMproved) for Mac OS X](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php)

Comment: vim is nice, loved it on ubuntu server. But binaries for mac has not been updated since 2007 on macvim.org :(

Comment: You could always use pure [vim](http://brilliantcorners.org/2011/02/building-vim-on-osx-snow-leopard/) built from source

Answer (score 0):

TextWrangler is a great free text editor.

http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/

Comment: I've used it before, but it didn't stick... something about graphics wasn't right, I just didn't like feel of it.